# I have a gcp storage bucket with 1000+ images in it. What's the easiest way to get a text file that lists all the URLs of objects in the bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I know that this api `https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<BUCKET_NAME>/o?` can be used to retrieve json data of 1000 objects at a time and and we can parse the output in code to pick out just the names and generate URLs of the required form. But is there a simpler way to generate a text file of list of URLs in a bucket?

edit: adding more details
I have configured a google load balancer(with CDN if that matters) with IP address <LB_IP> in front of this bucket. So ideally I would want to be able to generate a list of URLs like

```
http://<LB_IP>/image1.jpg  
http://<LB_IP>/image2.jpg
...
```

Comment: Can you use gsutil? Which output do you expect? Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general way you can just run in linux `gsutil ls gs://my_bucket > your_list.txt` to get all your objects in a text list.

If this is not what you are looking for please edit your question with more specific details.

Comment: thank you I have edited the q. While this does not give me URLs in the form I require I feel this is an easier way to retrieve object names than the way I have mentioned in the q

Answer (score 0):

gsutil doesn't have a command to print URLs for objects in a bucket, however it can list objects, as @Chris32 mentioned.

In addition, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609497/listing-all-public-links-for-all-objects-in-a-bucket-using-gsutil) Stackoverflow post you could combine listing to a sed program, to replace listings with object names and generate a form of URL.

For publicly visible objects, public links are predictable, as they match the following:

> https//storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME

Comment: thank you. Chris's answer combined with sed tool solves my issue