# Get Downloadable URL from firebase storage using command in .sh file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

in my Gcloud I have multiple folders and I have  mp4 files in these folders
so my question is how I can get the downloadable URL of this mp4 file using gsutil

Comment: Using which programming language?

Comment: this is one type of sh file for server uses

Comment: @AlexMamo can you have any idea about this

Answer (score 0):

Download URLs are a concept that only exists in Firebase. Google Cloud doesn't know anything about them, which also means they can't be generated by the `gsutil` tool. To generate download URLs you'll need to use a client-side Firebase SDK.

The closest equivalent to download URLs that Cloud knows of, are its [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). When used for downloads these are similar to Firebase's download URLs, but signed URLs always have a built-in expiration time.

Comment: Google Cloud has a public URL in the bucket using this public URL any user can easily access this file and I also have a Firebase SDK with google cloud 
my question is how I can get this with commands in my sh file.
and is it possible with a curl request or something else?

Comment: If you've made the entire bucket public, you can get URLs for each file/object in there by appending its name/path to the URL of the bucket. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67262810/how-to-get-list-of-public-urls-for-google-cloud-storage-with-nodejs-client-inste for an example of this. or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609497/listing-all-public-links-for-all-objects-in-a-bucket-using-gsutil

Comment: yes I already know that but my requirement is I need to send this public URL in an email to some specific people so I just need this URL using the command in my sh file 
but I have multiple folders and in these folders, I have multiple files so how I can get all file URLs one by one?


1. first how I can get my bucket folder name and his files one by one
2. how I can generate downloadable URLs of the files in this folder

Comment: The answers to the first two questions I linked show how to list files *and* generate URLs for them. If that is somehow not working for you, it's more likely we can help if you show what you've tried - as the approach in those answers should really be how to do that.

Comment: i am done with this stuck thanks for the your time